# How to make my laravel schedules works on AWS Fargate

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I just migrated my Laravel from AWS Beanstalk to AWS Fargate, and I have some schedules that I execute each day in my kernel.php. how I can execute them do I need to install cron in my container or there is a better way or alternative

thank you